# How is text saved in memory?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, decode, encode

Supposed there is a utf8-encoded file:

file1.txt

```
汉字
```

which binary representation is:

```
11100110 10110001 10001001 11100101 10101101 10010111
```

If I open it with an editor, which will read the bit sequence and decode it. I can see `汉字` in editor, and `汉字` will be saved in memory.

Then, now

- what is the bit sequence? Is it the same as above?
- Does it depend on platform?
- Is result ever same with various encoded text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As so often, the answer is "it depends".

Generally speaking in-memory text has to use some encoding just like on-disk text does.

But whether that encoding is the same as the on-disk one or not depends on the application.

Some might have a preferred encoding that they will represent the text in memory (such as UTF-16 or even UCS-4 if they are feeling wasteful) and others might hold it in-memory in the same encoding as used on-disk and just interpret it as necessary when rendering/searching.

There's no universal rule that requires one approach or another. Some languages/platforms have a strong preference.

For example Java uses UTF-16 for in-memory `String` objects (except as an internal optimization it might sometimes use Latin-1 if the text allows it).

Comment: The platform, you mean application, thus it is OS-independent? So, Unicode is also an option for saving in memory? And, whether utf8 always be decoded to Unicode, other encodes are not necessarily?

Comment: "Unicode" in itself is not an encoding (unless you count UCS-2 which was at some point considered synonymous with Unicode, but that's from a long gone era). By "platform" I mostly mean programming languages and their respective runtimes. Sometimes they are dependant/related to the OS (for example coding C on Windows *tends* to lean heavily on Windows internals, but Java works pretty much the same on either Windows or Unix-like OSes). UCS-4 is the closest you can get to "Unicode" as an encoding: its a fixed-with 4-byte encoding where each Unicode codepoint is represented by exactly 4 bytes.

Comment: @JoachimSauer "*For example Java uses UTF-16 for in-memory String objects*" - a lot of other languages/frameworks also use UTF-16 for in-memory strings. However, do note that Java strings are [not always UTF-16 in memory](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-compact-string) (see [JEP 254](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254)), but the programing interface to work with Java strings is still designed for UTF-16 access.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: @JoachimSauer you are right, I didn't see that point earlier. I still wanted to point out that Java is not the only language that represents strings in memory using UTF-16. C#, iOS, Delphi, etc, just to name a few